# How to redirect from a aspx query string url to wordpress

Tags: asp.net, database, wordpress, query-string, redirect

I have a 2 problem that is, I have to redesign an Aspx website to a WordPress website everything till now was fine but:
there are some query strings in aspx that show the students certificates directly, for example, http://www.example.ac.ir/Auth.aspx?id=184182187190184239218183181181182181
I want to redirect this kind of URL that Ids are variable to a WordPress page and show this certificate in WordPress directly
our old student’s certificates also have these URLs on it that they can scan their QR code to get access to it, because of this I don’t want that when a user request for old URL be faced with 404 error page
Example:
I want to redirect:
http://www.example.ac.ir/Auth.aspx?id=184182187190184239218183181181182181
Or:
http://www.example.ac.ir/ga.aspx?id=M3S941301026821
(these are old Aspx version of the website)
to:
http://www.example.ac.ir/Auth.php?id=184182187190184239218183181181182181
Or:
http://www.example.ac.ir/ga.php?id=M3S941301026821
(these should be new WordPress version of the website)

problem 2:
problem 2 is about PHP code, where can I find a tutorial that makes PHP page or plugin that convert aspx to PHP and read from non WordPress structured database??
I want to design that certificate pages in WordPress

note: if there is a way that I use aspx pages in WordPress without rendering such as  it can resolve my problem, too

Comment: please restrict your question to one issue at a time. If you have a second question, please post it separately. Otherwise your post can be closed as being too broad.

Comment: Anyway for the first question you can either amend the aspx to now just do a redirect to the new destination, or if you don't want to change the code you can implement rewrite rules via IIS (you can google IIS rewrite rules easily)

Comment: which webserver are you using? IIS or Apache? As far as I know, ASP.NET doesn't run in Apache so I'd assume your server runs IIS? Unless you are planning to replace the entire server and just redirect your domain name to point to the new one? I ask because htaccess is only for Apache. In IIS the equivalent is an [IIS Rewrite Rule](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Comment: Nginx can't serve asp.net applications directly so I assume you're either planning to replace IIS with nginx, or you're already using it as a reverse proxy in front of IIS. Will you be serving PHP pages directly through nginx or just proxying them onwards to IIS/Apache? Either way I would suggest it would be more efficient to use an nginx rewrite rule than a htaccess file. See https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/amp/ for some examples, there are other websites which show examples too. You need to ensure you understand the right tools to use in your particular environment

Answer (score 0):

On your Auth.aspx page,Make a Response.Redirect() to your PHP page:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.example.ir/Auth.php?id=" + Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString());
```

Comment: old website with aspx pages will be deleted - مرسی امین جان بابت پاسخت اما  سایت قبلی که با ای اس پی نوشته شده به کل پاک میشه و میخوام این نمایش مدارک دانشجویان رو توی وردپرس پیاده کنم
بخاطر همین میخوام وقتی دانشجو که آدرس قدیمی سایت (+آیدی ) رو تو مدرکش داره وقتی وارد همون آدرس رو اسکن میکنه و وارد سایت میشه ریدارت بشه به آدرس جدیدی که در وردپرس هستش

Comment: @amir please write in English only. Anyway if your old website is going to be deleted, if you want redirects to work you will have to retain the domain name and hosting so that you can have a place for requests to the old URL to go to. Then you must redirect users from there to the new one. If the whole thing ceases to exist then they'll simply get a connection error, and you would have no control over that

Comment: You should create your redirect rules in php or you can do it with creating rules on htaccess file

Comment: @AminMozhgani if the redirect must happen from the aspx app to the PHP app then how is a redirect in the PHP going to to help?? If the user already visited the PHP side (in order to trigger the redirect) then they are already in the right place. The redirection code must be located and written in such a way so that when users visit the old URL they are automatically sent to the new one.

Comment: @amir however in your question I just noticed it looks like you intend to host the new site in the same domain as the old one. so if you write your rewrite rules in the webserver (IIS or Apache I assume?) then you can achieve your goal while still deleting the aspx files.